# Could validation data be a generator (while training data is Array) in tensorflow.keras 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to train a model with `tensorflow.keras`. And I hope to do some other things between every training step, that's why I can not use `fit_generator` to train my model. In the other words, I hope to train model by looping `fit` function like follows:

```
training_data_generator = ...
validation_data_generator = ...
for i in range(steps_number):
    x, y = next(training_data_generator )
    net.fit(x, y)
    do_other_things_function()
    if steps_number%100==0:
        net.fit(x, y, validation_data = validation_data_generator)
```

But it failed. The reason may be that my training data is a numpy array in  `net.fit(x, y, validation_data = validation_data_generator)`, but my validation data is a generator.

So my question is: how to use a numpy array as training data and generaor as validation data at the same time??

Comment: would you like some code example or do you not agree with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you turn your train data into a generator and use `fit_generator()` instead of `fit()`

There are more ways to tackle this, first, look at [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47623/how-feed-a-numpy-array-in-batches-in-keras) question about how to change NumPy array to a generator, and if you need a more robust and detailed explanation look at [this](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) post.

Comment: Sorry, I have to use `fit` instead of `fit_generator`. I have given the reason above. I need do some things between each batch which can be achieved by `fit_generator`.

Comment: depending on what you need to do you may create a custom [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) to do what you want. You can find more implementation detail [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback#model_methods_that_take_callbacks). Basically you can call a method on `batch_end()` to do what you wish.

Comment: thanks, I want to train 2 U-net models alternately which share the same encoder. Say I train the first U-net on one batch of data, then train the second U-net on another one batch of data with the same encoder and a different decoder. Then train the first again ...

Comment: could you give me some advice about how to achieve it using `fit_generator`?